# Get radio button value from while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, radio-button

how can I get radio button's value from while loop?

this is my code for retrieve data from database:

```
<form action="verify.php" method="POST">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE ID_Q LIKE 'A%'" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

$kira=1;
while($x = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>$kira.</td>";
  echo "<th>" . $x['Question']."</th>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td>";
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM answer WHERE ID_question ='$x[ID_Q]'" ;
  $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
  $count2=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
  while($y = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
      echo "<input type='radio' name=answer[".$x['ID_Q']."] value=val[".$y['weight_pre']."]>".$y['answer'];
     echo "<br>";
  }
  echo "</td>";
  //echo "<td>".$x['pic']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $kira++;
  }
?>
<button type="submit"> Kira </button>
</form>
```

and this is my "verify.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
$a=$_GET['name'];
$b=$_GET['value'];
$c=$_SESSION['ID_user'];

 if(!isset ($_SESSION['ID_user'])){
    echo "You have to log in to be able to view this page.";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='1;index.php'>";
    die();
}
else {
    // Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$s=0;
while ($s<=20){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO answer_user(ID_user, ID_question, answer, 
weight) "."VALUES ('$c','$a','','$b')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$s++;
}

}
?>
```

so, how can I get the radio button's value once the user submit their form? thanks.

Comment: All your attributes for the radio button needs quotes. You never close the input element. What is the question mark in that element? Don't pass user input directly in your SQL, use prepared statements, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: sorry. that question mark is some sort of typo and thanks for your advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:

```
$_POST['radio'];
```

Replace "radio" with whatever your name of your radio inputs are.

Comment: i've tried that. and it's still not working. it's only insert the ID but not the data.

Comment: Do this. `$radio =$_REQUEST['radio'];` and then call $radio where you need it. If that doesn't work, I think I know why.

Comment: i've got the value (shown in the url) but it still didn't store in database. :(

Comment: What are you trying to do once you get the value of the radio button from the database? Are you saying it's not even submitting the value to the database?

Comment: I want to store the values in database. and yes, it not even submitting the value to the database.